# Export Gradle subproject in jar without adding it to dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, build

I have a Gradle project with 3 subprojects : `core`, `1_13`, and `1_14`. The `1_13` and `1_14` depends on the `core` project, but the final build has to be done on the `core` project, and I wanted to include the builds of the `1_13` and `1_14` in the jar.
The `1_13` and `1_14` subprojects have deps that aren't in the `core` subproject.

Actually, I use the `sourceSets` to include the source files of the `1_13` and `1_14` projects, but the fact that there are dependencies in the subprojects that doesn't exist in the `core` subproject, and that I can't use `apiElements` in the dependencies of the `core` subproject, because if I do a circular import occurs gets me stuck.

Actually, I use this :

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'src', '../1_13/src', '../1_14/src'
            resources {
                srcDir 'resources'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But because the libs are not present in the core subprojects, the build fails.
I precise that I only need the libs at the compile time, and not at runtime. I also can't add the libs to the `core` subproject because the submodules uses different versions of the same library. The core module is only here to route on whether one or another package should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After continuing to search for a while, I found the way to do exactly what I want using a Gradle task.

Actually, I created a task to combine all the jar files of the different modules :

```
task buildPlugin(type: Jar, group: 'build') {
    // Change the archive name and include all outputs of build of modules
    archiveFileName = "${rootProject.name}.jar"
    from getRootProject().allprojects.findAll().sourceSets.main.output

    // Delete the old jar of the core module, to keep only the finally build jar file
    doLast {
        var oldJar = new File(project.buildDir, "libs/" + project.name + "-" + project.version + ".jar")
        if (oldJar.exists()) {
            oldJar.delete()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way would be to extract the common logic that is used by `1_13` and `1_14` to a new project (e.g. `common`) and add `1_13` and `1_14` as real dependencies to the core project.

You could of course hack something like „use the dependencies of the subprojects as dependencies of the core project“ but hacks like this usually cause more trouble later on.

Comment: One of the way I found to resolve this was to create another subproject to avoid cycling, like `api` that only contained the common classes and to provide to the `1_13` and `1_14` a factory (abstracted in the api) to instantiate the api classes. That avoids cycling deps, but it's a lot more painful to setup and maintain. (It's what you said as I understood)

Comment: Well, yes. This would be the best way of doing it. What exactly makes this setup painful and difficult to maintain? We have like 100 projects in a single workspace and it working quite well.

Comment: @RedDev Otherwise, why do you have subprojects in the first place? The easiest way would be to move everything to the `core` project and you're done.

Comment: I can't move everything to the core project because in the different modules, I use different versions of the same library, and that's not allowed by Gradle, but I found a solution to do exactly what I want, I'll add an answer and mark as resolved ! Thank you for your help :)